# MySQL: select if `field` = TRUE else grab the last row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table I use to schedule content. Currently I grab the last row in the table via this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`schedule`) 
WHERE `date` <= '2014-06-06' 
ORDER BY `date` desc 
LIMIT 1
```

I also have a field called `demo` and I would like to develop this query to first find the row   `WHERE demo =  1` and if none of the rows contain a demo = 1 value then default to the current `WHERE date <= '2014-06-06' ORDER BY date desc`

Is there a way to accomplish this in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

Below Query will help you

```
SELECT * FROM schedule
WHERE CASE WHEN demo = 1 THEN
'2014-06-06' ELSE
date END <= '2014-06-06' 
ORDER BY date desc 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM `schedule`
WHERE demo=1
UNION
SELECT * FROM `schedule`
WHERE `date` <= '2014-06-06' 
ORDER BY `date` desc 
LIMIT 1
```

**Explanation:**

Using `UNION` the records with demo=1 are combined with the other query result.